# negative number of users with 1+ rep?

Tags: bug, statistics

Looks like there's a bug on the [Top Users Stack Overflow](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow) page - I'm seeing a negative number of users with 1+ rep:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't say that for me.

Comment: Maybe browser/system matters? - I'm looking at this on Chrome for Mac (Edit - Firefox and Safari on my mac show the same thing)

Comment: @AustinHenley there are two tables, maybe you are watching the first one?

Comment: It shows negative for me too - Safari on Mac.

Comment: It shows for me in Chrome v23.0.1271.97 on Windows 7.

Comment: I also see this. This is definitely not browser-dependent.

Comment: 4,294,716,597 users with 1+ rep... That sounds a little to high.

Comment: @Dennis Where did you see that number?

Comment: @irrelephant: `(unsigned) -250699`

Comment: The numbers are different for `week`, `month`, `quarter`, and `all time`.

Comment: It works fine for me in W7 Chrome 23 for all periods of time.

Comment: Looks like it fixed itself this morning - refreshing the page shows a normal looking 1,356,717 now.